# I have built and made a .zip of my app. Now what?

Tags: xcode, itunes, submission

I'm brand new to app programming, so hopefully, this should be a pretty quick question.  After using XCode, I've built and made a .zip of my app.  It's stored on my desktop for easy access.

Now what?  Do I have to do anything specific before I begin the submission routine for iTunes?  Or is the zip all I need to begin submission?

I've been reading http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/checklist.html, and it looks like I just finished Step 3.  Step 4 shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm a little confused about Step 5.  How and where do I select this SKU?

Once that's sorted out and Step 5 is finished and I'm on Step 6, how do I take these specific sized screenshots?  Do I just open the iPhone simulator and cmd+4 the window content?

After that, what should I do?  Help!!

As you can tell I'm a little overwhelmed!  Any advice anyone can give me will be really helpful.  I don't want my app to be rejected because I screwed up somewhere.

Which, brings me to my final, hopefully I'll never have to worry about them, questions... if my app is rejected for some reason or another, am I allowed to make changes and resubmit?  Or am I out of luck?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also have the .ipa's completed as well.  I thought it just made .zips until I just looked at what was created by XCode.  Sorry for any confusion this could have caused.

Answer (score 1):

Step 5 -- The SKU is just a # you put in that is supposed to help you keep track of your 'product' - the app. It can be anything, it's only used to help you (SKU = product ID #)... make one up for your app. Enter it on the same form you enter the description.

Step 6 - Yep, take the screenshots within the simulator, that's the easiest way IMO.

If your app is rejected, you can keep re-submitting til it gets in the store. Just remember it takes some time (was about a week for me) to review each app submission.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make screenshots easily by pressing the Home and the Sleep button on your iPhone / iPad simultaneously. The screenshot will be saved as a Photo on your Device.